# Lyx citation and math paste error

Tags: latex, lyx

Im trying to copy and paste citations and inline math code from one Lyx document I wrote to another.
Unfortunately when I paste into the new document the citations and the inline math code are not highlighted in grey anymore. Please see the figure attached.
This copy and paste function within Lyx was working yesterday and stopped working today.
Any idea how I can just copy and paste the citations and inline math code in the form they are in within the old document?

Thanks in advance,
K[image: Copy and pasting error within Lyx]

Comment: I tried to reproduce but this works well for me on Ubuntu. I'm not sure what's wrong, but it seems that when you paste, it is being treated as plain text. Can you try opening both old and new documents in the *same* LyX instance? To make sure you do this, first start LyX, then from inside LyX open both documents. Does it work then? If not, do you by chance have a clipboard manager?